# Map export in original resolution

Tags: qgis, export

My map file is approximately one pixel = 10 meters.

I want to keep that relationship when I export the map as an image.

So I want to export it with original resolution.

How do I achieve that in QGIS 3.2.3?

Comment: Isn't map composer actually print composer, which takes you back to grappling with dpi's and page sizes? I've imported a GeoTIFF to Qgis, now I want to export it. The print composer launches into talking about adding legends, borders, titles, etc. Having heard Qgis was the go to GIS tool, I was expecting it to be able manipulate GeoTIFF creation. Are you saying that Qgis has no GeoTIFF export?

Answer (score 2):

Use the map composer, set the necessary size for your canvas, add a map-element and let it display anything your map will have to contain. Then export it as an image.

Comment: Just a small extension of @Erik answer, when you export a map as a raster in QGIS, you are able to choose the resolution/quality (dpi) which you require.

Comment: "Let it display anything your map will have to contain" How do I do that?

Comment: By turning it on and refreshing the map --> https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html